# Equivalent of Order By operation in HBase

Tags: sql, hbase

Am working on a project which uses HBase. Even though I formed the rowkey as good as possible, still in some scenarios I need to get the results in either ascending or descending order.
Is there anything in HBase which is equivalent to "order by" operation in MySQL?
Or is Order By on a specific column qualifier possible in HBase?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No; you need to read the data in the order it's sorted in the row key, then do your own sort (e.g. in java or whatever language you're using).

Comment: I knew that i would have to implement the sort order using the rowkey itself.Anyway, thanks for the reply.

Comment: @JayanK: In case, you really need Order By feature on non rowkey data. Then Apache Phoenix supports that query.

Answer (score 3):

I know post is old but for future reference. Scan (Hbase 0.98+) now supports `setReversed`

```
public Scan setReversed(boolean reversed)
  Set whether this scan is a reversed one
  This is false by default which means forward(normal) scan.

Parameters:
 reversed - if true, scan will be backward order
Returns:
```

Ref:- [Hbase Scan Tutorial](http://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/client/Scan.html)